# MongoDb Update error: Maximum serialization depth exceeded

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I am new to Mongodb, so please execute if my question is elementary. I am using the Mongodb C# driver in my ASP.net MVC project. However, while executing the MongoDb C# update operation, I am hitting this error

**Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.**

**Exception Details: MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?).**

Here is the object model class. Is the error due to the below line, which is there in my model class?

**public List OutGoingFriendRequestList { get; set; }**

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UserDescription { get; set; }


    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public List<UserProfileViewModel> OutGoingFriendRequestList { get; set; }



  }
}
```

And here is the Controller Action Method in which I try to do the update

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddFriend(UserProfileViewModel model)
{

  //Get the database connection instance and then get the collection
  var _database = SocialNetworkHelper.ReturnMongoDbInstance();

   IMongoCollection<UserProfileViewModel> collection =  

   _database.GetCollection<UserProfileViewModel>("Facebook_Lite");

    //In the next 2 sentences, I am filtering using the userId field
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var filter = Builders<UserProfileViewModel>.Filter.Eq("UserId", User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    result.Wait();
    UserProfileViewModel userProfileViewModelInstance = result.Result.ElementAt(0);

    List<UserProfileViewModel> OutgoingFriendRequestList = userProfileViewModelInstance.OutGoingFriendRequestList;

    OutgoingFriendRequestList.Add(friendUserModelInstance);

    userProfileViewModelInstance.OutGoingFriendRequestList = OutgoingFriendRequestList;

    var update = Builders<UserProfileViewModel>.Update.Set("OutGoingFriendRequestList", userProfileViewModelInstance.OutGoingFriendRequestList);

    //I am hitting the exception on the below line
    **var updateResult = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);**

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { userid = friendUserId });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you represent a tree like model like yours is by holding references to children/leaves, not the objects themselves. Instead of:

`public List<UserProfileViewModel> OutGoingFriendRequestList { get; set; }`

you should store ids of these database redords.

`public List<ObjectId> OutGoingFriendRequestList { get; set; }`